# .txt file shows chinese symbols / c++

Tags: c++

So I'm writing this program in C++ for school and everything looks ok until I open the .txt file... all I can see are Chinese symbols.. Anyone with an idea?

That's my code. Dont mind the unfinished search function and other stuff.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

fstream data_file;
struct depositor
{
    char name[20];
    char last_name[30];
    char address[60];
};

void add_depositor(depositor p_Info);
void search_depositor();

void add_depositor(depositor p_Info)
{
    data_file.open("Data.txt", ios::app);
    if (data_file.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error while opening the file!";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        data_file.write((char*)(&p_Info), sizeof(depositor));
        data_file.close();
    }
}

int menu()
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        cout << "\n* Menu *";
        cout << "\n* 1. Add depositor! *";
        cout << "\n* 2. Search for depositor! *";
        cout << "\n* 3. Exit program! *";
        cout << "\n* Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << "\n* You chose: " << choice;
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 4);
    return choice;
}
void main()
{
    depositor p; int choice;
    do
    {
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: cout << "\n Enter first name: ";
            cin >> p.name;
            cout << "\n Enter last name:  ";
            cin >> p.last_name;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
            cout << "\n Enter address: ";
            cin.getline(p.address, 60);
            add_depositor(p); break;
        case 2: cout << "";
        default: cout << "\n* End of program! *";
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
}
```

And this is what I get in the txt file:

[image]

Comment: and what do you expect to see?

Comment: Notepad is misinterpreting the file because it has binary data in it. You need to write only text.

Comment: @MarkRansom: What "binary data" would that be?

Comment: @MarkRansom I was writing only text

Comment: @Puff no you were writing a structure, with uninitialized characters in it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit whatever garbage was after the ends of the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you're just dumping whatever you have in your structure into the text file (whether it is good data or not). You might want to space delimit the individual methods and output using << instead of write.

```
data_file << p_Info.name << ' ' << p_Info.last_name << ' ' << p_Info.address;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are writing the object data to the file :

```
  data_file.write((char*)(&p_Info), sizeof(depositor));
```

The data stored is not encoded to be read by text editors. It however can be used for object serialization for later retrieval.

To store the data in the text form, which can be seen with notepad :

```
 data_file << p_Info.name << " "<<p_Info.last_name<<" " << p_Info.address << "\n";
```

In this way the data is stored in the ASCII format.

If you need to serialize objects,

```
data_file.open("Data.dat", ios::app | ios::binary); //Its not a text file anymore and has to be opened in binary mode.
if(!data_file){
  cout<<"\nError";
}
else{
  data_file.write((char*)(&p_Info), sizeof(depositor));
}
data_file.close();
```

Comment: An up vote would have been better than a thank you comment! :)

Comment: I just made my acc... It says that i need atleast 15 rep :D

Comment: What is this "binary form" of which you speak? There is no "binary format" vs "ASCII format" -- that's an abstraction for control over file streams and terminals, and is not in play here. In both pieces of code you are simply writing _bytes_ into a _file_ and those _bytes_ represent _characters_. Those characters can and will be represented as ASCII.

Comment: The way the data is held in the memory during runtime.

Comment: @ShikharBhardwaj: Then tell me how that "way" differs between the two examples.

Comment: Ok I agree we are writing binary data in both the examples. What differs is the encoding.